# Getting hostname in MVC controller constructor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is it possible to get the current hostname from the controller constructor?

Both the Request and HttpContext objects are null, so Request.Url yields nothing.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyEntities _entities;

    public HomeController()
    {
        //
        var hostname = Request.Url;
        if (hostname.Contains("localhost")) EFConnectionStringName="localhost";
        else EFConnectionStringName="default";
        _entities = new MyEntities(EFConnectionStringName);
    }
...
```

The greater problem I am trying to solve here is to choose a connection string for Entity Framework based upon the hostname. Ideas?

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541635/how-do-i-find-fully-qualified-hostname-of-my-machine-in-c

Comment: Taking that it says "localhost" in your code I suspect you want to use a seperate connection when you are debugging? Why not just use a web.debug.config file? See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx

Comment: There will be a few more hostnames that need to be included for different environments, maybe 6 in total. Yes, I'm aware this is not best practice, but the decision was made and I'm following orders.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Request` is indeed null during the **construction** of your Controller. Try this instead:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    var hostname = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;

    // do something based on 'hostname' value
    // ....

    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

Also, please note that `Request.Url` will not return the hostname but a `Uri` object from which you can extract the hostname using `Url.Host`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).

Comment: Is this no longer possible in ASP.NET 5 preview?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        Debug.Print("Host:" + Request.Url.Host); // Accessible here
        if (Request.Url.Host == "localhost")
        {
            // Do what you want for localhost
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that `Request.Url` is an `Uri` object, so you should check `Request.Url.Host`

Comment: Beautiful, thanks for your reply! I'm sorry I can only mark one answer as accepted. Both yours and haim770's answers did the job perfectly.

Comment: If someone happens to be looking a way of blocking requests based on localhost (e.g, a controller only for local tests), it is possible to write the follow to prevent actions from being executed:
    `filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    Dispose(); //Important`

Answer (score 0):

Request URL's host doesn't necessarily have to match the hosting server name. For example if you're using DNS CNAMEs or loadbalancers.

If you'd like the machine name of the server hosting the code, try this in your controller action:

```
string hostingMachineName = HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Server.MachineName;
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I'm looking for because of the load balancing scenario you mentioned, unfortunately my HttpContext doesn't have the ApplicationInstance object. What am I missing? I'm using ASP.net Core 1.1.0, is this only available in regular the .net framework?

Answer (score 0):

```
current pc host :-
string PCName = Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]).HostName;   

server host :-
String hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
```