# How to get full host name

Tags: c#, netbios

Enviroment.MachineName returns short name:

```
public static string GetCurrentMachineName()
{
    return GetMachineName(Environment.MachineName); //returns hostname
}
```

I have short hostname: `shortName` and fullname: `shortName.company.local`.
So, when i call `GetCurrentMachineName()` i get only `shortName` instead 'shortName.company.local'.
What can be wrong?

P.S.:
It is not work for me: for example, my hostname is `hostname1`. 
And my friend at current network has hostname named `hostname2`. So, when i execute this code:

```
return System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName;
```

with hostname2 it resolve to `hostname2.company.local` and `hostname1` to my hostname.

Comment: Sounds like you want the [DNS host name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233217/difference-between-systeminformation-computername-environment-machinename-and).

Comment: Please refer to:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541635/how-do-i-find-the-fully-qualified-hostname-of-my-machine-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve ,my problem:

1. Flush DNS cache

   ipconfig /flushdns
2. Clear my `hosts` file.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 3):

Use this `Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName` to get full host name

```
public static string GetCurrentMachineName()
    {
        return System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("").HostName; //returns hostname
    }
```

Comment: It is not work for me:
for example, my hostname is hostname1. And my friend at current network has hostname named hostmane2.
So, when i execute your code with `hostname2` it resolve to `hostname.company.local` and `hostname1` for me.